# Replace control in repeater with another control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater that has a text box and when I enter edit mode on my repeater, I want to replace the text box with a dropdownlist of available options. Is there a way to remove the text box upon item databind and replace it with a dropdownlist for the selected rows index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use whatever you are using to indicate edit mode and edit index in the OnItemDataBound event. Then the easiest way is to just hide the text box and show the dropdownlist instead. Whether this works for you or not is dependent on what you're trying to do.